# Uncaught Reference Error: function name is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, function, button, onclick

This is the edited version of my previous question.
here i want make a ajax request to fetch class(row name of a table from database). first function is working fine but second function throw this error.

and when i put these two function in different functions first one work and second throw error but when i put both in same tag both are giving error.
hope you understand.

Code is

```js
function showoptionss(str) {
  if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("options1").innerHTML = "";
    return;
  }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("options1").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "getdata.php?q=" + str, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
};

function gettotalcost() {
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var gottotalcost = this.responseText;
      alert(this.responseText);
      document.getElementById("total_cost").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  }
  var itemtype = document.getElementById("itemtype").value;
  var options1 = document.getElementById("options1").value;
  var subs = document.getElementById("subs").value;
  xmlhttp.open("GET","calculate.php?type="+str+"&options1="options1+"&subs="+subs,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
};
```

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST">
  <div class="box-body">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Type</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <select class="form-control select2" name="type" id="itemtype" onchange="showoptionss(this.value)" style="width: 100%;">
          <option> Veg </option>
          <option> Non_veg </option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Class</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <select id="options1" class="form-control select2" name="class" style="width: 100%;">
        <?php
          $optionquery = "SELECT * FROM `prices` WHERE `dot`='Thaali' && `type`='Veg'";
          $optionquery_result = mysqli_query($con,$optionquery) or exit("Error in getting data");
          while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($optionquery_result)) {
            echo "<option>".$r['class']."</option>";
          }
        ?>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Quantity</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="quantity" required name="quantity" max="100" min="1" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Quantity">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Your Address</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" required name="your_address" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Your Address">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Subscription</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <select class="form-control select2" value="<?php echo $subs; ?>" id="subs" name="subs" style="width: 100%;">
          <option> Today </option>
          <option> Monthly </option>
          <option> Quaterly </option>
          <option> Half_yearly </option>
          <option> Yearly </option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Time</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="time" class="form-control" required value="<?php echo $time; ?>" name="time" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Pickup Address">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputPassword3" name="total_cost" id="total_cost" required class="col-sm-2 control-label">Total Cost</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" disabled value="<?php echo $total_cost; ?>" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Total Cost">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.box-body -->
  <div class="box-footer" id="f">

    <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="gettotalcost()" name="calculate" value="Calculate" />
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right" name="order" value="Order" />
  </div>
  <!-- /.box-footer -->
</form>
```

Comment: You were missing a `}` - creating a snippet immediately gives console error - also w3schools is not a very recommended site to use. MDN is better

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Comment: @mplungjan ok thanks but what is the problam in this code why i can't make two javascript function in one script tag.

Comment: What do you mean? You can do `onclick="myFunction(); myFunction1()"` in one button and both your functions work when you add the `}` after `"Hello World by second";`

Comment: Feel free to delete the question since it is not really useful to anyone but you

Comment: @mplungjan ok i am deleteing question.

Comment: @mplungjan but have  the same problam in my ajax code where i make two different function for two different work.

Comment: So AMEND the question to reflect the actual situation. Please UPDATE the snippet to have a [mcve]

Comment: @mplungjan please see this edit and help me

Comment: Typo - missing `+` here `xmlhttp.open("GET", "calculate.php?type=" + str + "&options1="` ---- `options1 + "&subs=" + subs, true);` 
`

Comment: @mplungjan but this function not even open it is throwing this error "Uncaught ReferenceError: gettotalcost is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick"

Comment: 1. Do you have the functions inside an onload handler, then move them out. 2. str is not defined here `xmlhttp.open("GET", "calculate.php?type=" + str + "&options1="+options1 + "&subs=" + subs, true);`

Comment: no this function is called when we click calculate button in form and

Comment: You use str instead of itemtype

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/du13e2c7/ right click on bottom right frame and choose "view frame source" - apart from the CDATA comments that you can ignore, that is how you want the code to look like. The fiddle will not work since I did not wire up the Ajax, but the page gives no other errors

Comment: @mplungjan thanks sir you helped me lot thank you very much from my 
bottom heart.

Comment: You are welcome. Please delete the question since it is VERY local to you and your issues

Answer (score 0):

just a syntax error ;) mising `}` at `myFunction1()`

https://jsfiddle.net/6z9sp003/

have a nice day

Comment: why downvoting this?

Comment: Because it is a typo and answering it will disallow deleting. The answer is already in the comment - additionally you could have made a snippet instead of a fiddle - also the missing bracket was in function1

Comment: you could also have your answer posted as an answer instead of a comment wtf.....

Comment: tedious to go through fiddle for this.

Comment: Why not here. Why do we have to leave the SO environment when you can just click the `<>` and make a snippet

Comment: And no, I did not post an answer since it is not worth answering - there is no value in keeping this question around and answering it will stop OP from deleting it

Comment: @messerbill Thanks bro

Comment: thats why i also posted the problem directly in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Missing }; at the end of myFunction1()